# AWS Encryption SDK For GO?

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, aws-sdk-go

I used the AWS Encryption SDK CLI (2.0.0) to encrypt a text file (hello.txt) using a Customer Managed Key (CMK) in AWS KMS service. After that i uploaded the encrypted text file (hello.txt.encrypted) through the AWS console to S3.

Then i can download this encrypted text file with this usual call:

```
results, err := s.s3Client.GetObject(&s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
        Key:    aws.String(item),
    })
```

As a next step i want to then decrypt this text file in Go. But i am unable to find a AWS Encryption SDK for go for decryption that will let me do this.

This is what i would do in AWS Encryption SDK for Java .

```
AwsCrypto crypto = AwsCrypto.standard();
final KmsMasterKeyProvider prov = KmsMasterKeyProvider.builder().buildDiscovery();
final CryptoResult<byte[], KmsMasterKey> decryptResult = crypto.decryptData(prov, responseBytes);
```

I am looking for ways to do the same thing in Go. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Currently, the AWS Encryption SDK [does not support Go](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/programming-languages.html). I would not advise to write one for yourself

Comment: Are there any third party libraries out there that can do this in Go? 

The only other solution i can think of is to use KMS with data keys for encryption for the S3 object. There is support for that in AWS-SDK-GO.

Comment: Remember that the SDK provides easy-to-use routines and tries to avoid common cryptographic mistakes (e.g using the same IV over and over) as much as possible. If you understand cryptography, you're welcome to use Go's native libraries. Otherwise, your best bet would be using the [CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/crypto-cli.html)

Comment: Since cognito use aws encryption sdk to encrypt the confirmation Code to be sent by mail. Is there, in 2022, a way to use encryption sdk in golang ? What a shame from aws..

Comment: There is no way yet to decrypt the keys that are encrypted with the aws-crypto library, the way I solved it is to make a lambda that will decrypt the key and call it from the lambda in golang